# Implementing dynamic radius to radius neighbor classifier for better class imbalance handling

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imbalanced-data

I am trying to create dynamic radius based radius neighbour classifier for one multiclass classification problem. This dataset is havig 7 classses. I am giving different radius to each class and then passing it to radius neighbour classifier. My Code is something like this.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import RadiusNeighborsClassifier

# Define the dynamic radius values for each class
class_radius = {
    'class1': 0.5,
    'class2': 0.7,
    'class3': 0.6,
    'class4': 0.1,
    'class5': 0.2,
    'class6': 0.8,
    'class7':0.6
   
    # Add radius values for other classes if applicable
}

# Create a list to store the individual classifiers
classifiers = []

# Iterate over each class and create a Radius Neighbors Classifier with the specific radius
for class_label, radius in class_radius.items():
    # Select samples and labels for the current class
    X_class = X_resampled[y_resampled == class_label]
    y_class = y_resampled[y_resampled == class_label]

    if len(X_class) == 0:
        continue

    n_samples, n_features = X_class.shape
    print(X_class.shape)

    # Create a Radius Neighbors Classifier with the specified radius
    classifier = RadiusNeighborsClassifier(radius=radius)
    classifier.fit(X_class, y_class)
    accuracy = classifier.score(X_test, y_test)
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy)

    # Append the classifier to the list
    classifiers.append(classifier)
```

How to calculate accuracy on this case?